# When returning VO as json, how to return excluding null value?

Tags: java, spring, web, backend

When returning VO as json, how to return excluding null value?

```
     @RequestMapping("/rbtInfo.do")
     public RobotVO rbtInfo(@RequestParam String rbtId){
         String rbtPower = "ON";
         robot.setRbtPower(rbtPower);
         return robot;

     }
```

Above is my controller.

And the return value is as follows.

```
{
     "rbtId": null,
     "rbtPower": "ON",
     "rtspAddr": null,
     "ifrRtspAddr": null,
     "stationPosition": null,
}
```

In this case, I want to return only `rbtPower` for which the value exists, but not the rest.

How can I return excluding null data from VO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below annotation at class level or method level for RobotVO.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
```

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields